# Is it possible to replace this recursion with iteration?

Tags: c#, recursion

There are two kinds of Workers: Employee and Superior.
Superior has Subordinates collection, which items are either Employee or Superior.
Superior's salary depends on its all level Subordinates' salary.
At now I calculate Subordinates' salary with recursion:

```
decimal SubordinatesSalary()
{
  decimal salary = 0;
  foreach ( Worker subordinate in Subordinates )
  {
    salary = salary + subordinate.SalaryPrim();
    Superior subordinateAsSuperior = subordinate as Superior;
    if ( subordinateAsSuperior != null )
      salary = salary + subordinateAsSuperior.SubordinatesSalary();
  }
  return salary;
}
```

Is it possible to replace this recursion with iteration ?

Comment: Yes, it is always possible to replace recursion with iteration. But you probably interested in something more specific.

Comment: Yes, but why would you?  This is pretty much an ideal use of recursion.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Probably homework.

Comment: @Hogan, I unserstand, that's why I asked.

Comment: Sometimes recursion cause stack overflow exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  It is possible to replace any recursion with iteration.  It is really easy to do so with tail end recursion.  You just change it to a loop.  If it is not tail end then you need to store the local variables in a stack and push and pop from the stack (since this is all a recursive function call gives you).

While it looks at first like you have tail end recursion, you don't because it is in a loop.  You need to make an outer loop and push the local variables (like worker) when you loop to your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Take all people.

Order them by their "level" ("absolute position"). Lowest employees first. Then their superiors. Then their superiors. Then ... Then finally the topmost "president". Doing this correctly may be tricky.

Iterate over that employees list and assign salaries one-by-one. When you complete first batch of lowest-level employees, then you get to first-level superiors and you can calculate their salaries easily as all lower-level employees are already finished, and you are guaranteed that their salaries are already processed and you do not need to recursively "scan" the person's subordinates to calculate it.

But.. is it really reasonable? I think the current recursive way is pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all.
Here is my non-recursive solution:

```
decimal SubordinatesSalary()
{
  decimal salary = 0;
  Stack<Worker> stack = new Stack<Worker>( Subordinates );
  while ( stack.Count > 0 )
  {
    Worker subordinate = stack.Pop();
    salary = salary + subordinate.SalaryPrim();
    Superior subordinateAsSuperior = subordinate as Superior;
    if ( subordinateAsSuperior != null )
      foreach ( Worker subordinate2 in subordinateAsSuperior.Subordinates )
        stack.Push( subordinate2 );
  }
  return salary;
}
```